# Is it possible to access data through iDevice lightning port?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I threw together a simple MicroSD to lightning adapter. Bought a female lightning to USB adapter to test it on my computer and windows recognizes the SD card. So will iOS even see the SD card? Or will iOS not see it? Because if iOS can at least see that there is something connected to the lightning port, I should be able to put together a simple program in xcode to at least read the contents. With more research and a more advanced program could hopefully be able to mount the card to the filesystem. Jailbroken iPhone 6S on 9.0.2 btw. Kind of skeptical though because if expandable storage was possible, various iOS/cydia developers would've already made it possible.

Comment: This isn't a programming question. As written it's more of a hardware question.

Comment: Apple sells a lightning SD card adapter for importing photos into an iPad. I don't know if it works with iPhone or if Apple has exposed any APIs for accessing the storage.

Answer (score 6):

Apple provide a framework for communicating with accessories connected to 
Lightning (or indeed 30-pin) ports on iOS devices. It's called the External Accessories Framework, see here: [External Accessory Framework Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/ExternalAccessory/Reference/ExternalAccessoryFrameworkReference/index.html)

Should you wish to understand the hardware certification process for iOS hardware, details here: [Apple MFI Program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/mfi/)

Comment: @modernwar24 - if my comment answered your question, please mark it as correct using the grey tick? Many thanks.